# How to set Android dialog's size to match the dialog's layout size?

Tags: android, dialog

I have this xml which defines my dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView android:text="test"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my dialog:

```
OverlayItem item = mapOverlays.get(index);
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.map_menu);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
dialog.show();
```

For some reason my dialog is bigger then my "test" textview (much higher). I want my dialog to be exactly as my text. how can i do that ?

Comment: I don't have the API in front of me, but I think you need to set the dialogs width and height :

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set to dialog the option not to have a title.

So add this: `dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the API in front of me, but I think you need to set the dialog width and height parameters as something like:

```
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

You can also set the X,Y coordinates where to show the dialog by playing around with its window and setting its attributes before the show as well.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Title to your dialog then you can decrease your dialog size, or adjust sizes in your layout which is adjusted dialog view.

```
OverlayItem item = mapOverlays.get(index);

Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
// Removing Dialog 
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.map_menu);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
dialog.show();
```